# ApplicationVerificationFail during launching ios app with robovm & libgdx

Tags: libgdx, robovm

We are developing games with robovm(0.0.11) and libgdx(1.0.0), When we launching ios app on the ipad, there is an error tip: ApplicationVerificationFail.
But when I create a second game with the same signing identity and provisioning profile, it's OK!
So it is very strange, why our first game occured ApplicationVerificationFail on iPad device?
Any information will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem.

Because there is a png with chinese name, there will be ApplicationVerificationFail!
We must delete the Chinese png and rename app.mainClass and app.executable!
Hope it helpful to somebody!
thanks at the same!